# Can't get Apache2 to use PHP8.1 on Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: apache2, php

I have an Ubuntu server 20.04 installation that among other things is running a bare-metal Nextcloud instance using Apache as the web server. I have multiple PHP versions installed, but up to this point Apache was using PHP 7.4. Since Nextcloud deprecated it, I was trying to migrate to PHP 8.1 (the new recommended version, still no support for PHP 8.2). I tried following many guides on how to do this, all of them basically boil down to installing PHP 8.1 and the needed modules, use `a2dismod php7.4` to disable the old PHP version, enable the new one with `a2enmod php8.1` and restart Apache with `systemctl restart apache2`. This is the last one I followed: [link](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-php-8-1-on-ubuntu-20-04/).
But despite this, Apache keeps using PHP 7.4. If I try to uninstall PHP 7.4, my Nextcloud installation just breaks (I get a 503 error). I tried with slight variations, but always failed and ended up restoring the lvm snapshot I created before the attempt. But I still didn't restore the snapshot of the last attempt, here I did all the steps in the linked guide and I didn't uninstall PHP 7.4, so my Nextcloud is still working but using the wrong version. What can I check or try to fix this?
Thank you for your help,

GTP

Comment: Did you remember to use `update-alternatives` to set the default PHP version?

Comment: I didn't, but when I try to run `php -v` I either get PHP 8.1.something or PHP 8.2.something (depending on whether I also uninstall the PHP versions I don't need or not, the default is PHP 8.2.something). In no case do I get PHP 7.4. Does it still matter?

Comment: I just tried, but unfortunately it didn't work. After running `update-alternatives --config php` and selecting PHP 8.1 (before the default was PHP 8.2), if I do `php -v` from the terminal I get PHP 8.1.14, but Nextcloud is still running with PHP 7.4.33. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem turned out to be that I had two *different* websites (not Nextcloud itself) that in their .conf file inside the `sites-enabled` directory specifued PHP7.4-fpm as their handler as follows:
`SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"`
Disabling those fixed the problem. So it seems that Apache2 gets confused if one website specifies a version of PHP-fpm and the others don't, and ends up forcing that version to all websites. I'm leaving those disabled for now as I'm not using them, but I'll put a note somewhere to remember me to update their config or Nextcloud's config in case I wish to use them again.